How can we merge both PrimeNg Css and Bootstrap css to individual modules with out conflicts in Angular
I developed an Angular project three months ago, structured with both applications and a library using Bootstrap. Now, I need to migrate the entire project to PrimeNG components. I have rewritten the application components using PrimeNG, but due to time constraints, I am unable to migrate the library components to PrimeNG.
As a temporary solution, I want to merge the library components using Bootstrap with the main application components using PrimeNG CSS. However, I am encountering conflicts such as mixins and class tags, where PrimeNG CSS is being overridden by Bootstrap CSS.
How can I apply/load Bootstrap CSS only to the library components without causing conflicts with the main application?
I am using angular 18.1.0 version.
Packages for main application


"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^18.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3",
    "chart.js": "4.4.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.18.4",
    "quill": "2.0.2",
    "keycloak-angular": "^16.0.1",
    "keycloak-js": "^25.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^18.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.5.2"
  }



Packages for Library
{
  "name": "usermgmt",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^17.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^13.4.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.35",
    "intl-tel-input": "^23.3.2",
    "keycloak-angular": "^16.0.1",
    "keycloak-js": "^25.0.1",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^18.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^18.0.2",
    "ngx-export-as": "^1.16.0",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "highcharts": "10.2.1",
    "highcharts-angular": "3.0.0",
    "highcharts-custom-events": "^3.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "sideEffects": false
}


I am using angular 18.1.0 version.
styles.css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap');
@import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';

@import 'primeflex/primeflex.scss';
@import './assets/scss/project_variable';
@import './assets/tabler-icons/tabler-icons.scss';
@import './assets/scss/primengTheme/themes/mytheme/theme.scss';
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";


for bootstrap I created a custom css file but I unable to load that css file for library components.
custom-styles.css
    @import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
    @import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
    @import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs5-alert';
    @import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css';
    @import "@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
    @import 'ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.min.css';
   

I tried by maintaining the primeNg imports in global styles.scss file and created a custom scss file for bootstrap imports even loading this custom css file for library components not getting applied.
If I tried to import both primeNg and bootstrap css imports in global styles.scss file like below


/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap');
@import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';

@import 'primeflex/primeflex.scss';
@import './assets/scss/project_variable';
@import './assets/tabler-icons/tabler-icons.scss';
@import './assets/scss/primengTheme/themes/mytheme/theme.scss';
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";

@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs5-alert';
@import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css';
@import "@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
@import 'ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.min.css';

@import './assets/scss/mixin';

@import './assets/scss/globle';
@import './assets/scss/badge';
@import './assets/scss/tag';
@import './assets/scss/card';
@import './assets/scss/layout';
@import './assets/scss/header';
@import './assets/scss/sidemenu';
@import './assets/scss/table';
@import './assets/scss/breadcrumb';



I am getting following error in compilation
Error
